# search a UCS-2 file using batch

Tags: batch, findstr

I have a file that is encoded in UCS-2 that is constantly being updated. I need to keep checking this file for a string of recurring text and then  parsing the info. I originally tried using findstr but it wouldn't find the text. I tried saving the text string in a similarly encoded file, which worked but I couldn't use the output. I need to search a file with text similar to this

```
</DocStreifenRoot>'
  'Teile'='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<DocLauefe xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Lauefe>
    <Lauf Name="RB6">
      <ClassList>
        <Class Type="Teil">
          <TeilList>
            <Teil Anzahl="1" Nummer="150">
              <QualitaetList>
                <Qualitaet Anzahl="1" Name="" />
              </QualitaetList>
            </Teil>
          </TeilList>
        </Class>
      </ClassList>
    </Lauf>
  </Lauefe>
</DocLauefe>'
  'Total'='1'
  'Typ'='ReceiveMaterial'
  'UnicKey'='PS5-113\RB6\00005\1-1/0.2.0'
  'ZyklusName'='PS5-113\RB6\00005\1-1'

07.03.2019 15:09:45,163: HandleData: wanted (run) (pattern)RB6 00005
07.03.2019 15:09:45,207: HandleData: partsval exist
07.03.2019 15:09:45,246: --------used run: RB6
07.03.2019 15:09:45,287: Internal print: Handle event
07.03.2019 15:09:45,338: PrinterSystem_debug: sStreifenRoot
07.03.2019 15:09:45,382: PrinterSystem_debug: StreifenList
07.03.2019 15:09:45,421: PrinterSystem_debug: diffStripes
07.03.2019 15:09:45,462: PrinterSystem_debug: LageList
07.03.2019 15:09:45,504: PrinterSystem_debug: Entered_section_addinfo_run_and_part:RB6150
```

I want to find each occurrence of "Entered_section_addinfo_run_and_part". What I need is the data at the end of that line (RB6150 in this case) so I can use it to search another file. Is this something that can be done using Batch, or would I be better off going about this another way.

Update: I just noticed the encoding in the file says utf-16, but notepad++ had UCS-2 which is why I worded the question the way I did.

Answer (score 1):

Findstr does not support Unicode file, so you must first convert the file to ASCII.

You can use for that the free
[Sysinternals strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings)
utility which does support UCS-2 files:

```
"C:\path\to\strings.exe" yourfile.txt
```

Comment: thank you. I was able to get it done with this "strings "%file%" | findstr "Entered" >>%outputdata%"